# Google couldn't verify my Merchant payment method

Tags: android

I stumbled upon major issue I couldn't find any solution out on the internet.

So, I'm a long time developer who had an individual Google Play account for the last 4 years, and have 3 apps there. I never had a problem with Google Policy violations or any kind of warnings from them until now. I'll enumerate my steps which lead me to this agony.

1. I started a company for these apps and wanted to switch to the Business profile so I receive payments on my company bank account. I switched Dev account to Organization type and provided my company bank for payments. I didn't know at that time that it is not enoguh, I needed to have **Payments profile Business type** too. Payment profile type **cannot be changed** from Individual type to Business.
2. So Google Support told me I should create **brand new Developer account** for my company, and new Payment profile, Business type connected to it, which I did. I verified my identity, my company identity, DUNS number and all these went smooth. But when I wanted to connect my payment method for payouts, after I submitted the bank statement Google asked me to provide, they rejected it with declaration "Google couldn't find issuing authority on your bank statment". But issuing authority was there, along with all the info from the official bank statement.
3. I tried one more time, asked support for help but they just tossed me back and forth from one support team to another, until I closed the full circle after the last support team forwarded me to the first one.
4. After 3 weeks of tryng to verify my identity unsuccseffuly, I closed the Developer account.
5. I wanted to try one more time, this time bought Google Workspace and my company domain, and also developed a website for it (as Google said it might help with verification process).
6. Again, my identity, and my company identity went smooth, but when I submitted my payment method, Google blocked my account, with a notification "**Your developer profile and all apps will be removed from Google Play on 5 December 2023**" and the reason for it was "**Google couldn't verify your merchant payment method**". [Screenshot here](https://ibb.co/0nkgvjS)

At the same time, by bank statement is still in review. It's like Google automatically detected something fishy and blocked my account, before the Google review team even had a chance to review it.

**What I suspect**

Maybe the problem was because I had this payment method (my company) at the same time in 2 developer accounts (individual and business)?

I appealed, but I'm not sure what to do next. Support is again useless, and just forward me on the next team. Is there any way I can prove myself, and my company to Google? What to do next?

**Update**: My issue has been resolved. After I removed the company bank account from my original individual profile, the next review passed smoothly (Appeal + review of the payment method documents). Support didn't confirm this was the issue, but it is only thing I changed, and suddenly it was not an issue.

My guess is, Google detected same company bank account on 2 different Developer accounts, and they automatically rejected it with generic explanation.

Comment: I'm glad you got this resolved. Why this has to be so secretive stumps me. Amazon and Instagram are the same way.